# Control de temperatura con arduino

Tags: arduino

el sensor lm35 necesito que cuando la temperatura sea mayor o igual a 30 grados encienda un led1, y cuando sea menor la temperatura encienda el led 2 y se active el zumbador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

llevo esto hasta ahorita, porfavor necesito ayuda tengo un examen pronto.

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad, por favor considera leer [ask] y de paso hacer el [tour], el uso de imágenes no es bien visto pues como ya has podido notar no son muy viisibles, en su lugar copia y pega el código como texto, seleccionalo y presiona **ctrl + k**

Comment: De paso, incluye también la pregunta que tienes. Indicas qué quieres hacer y un código pero no sabemos cuál es el problema

Answer (score 2):

Un problema que veo en tu código es que el sensor [LM35](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm35.pdf) es un sensor que da una lectura analógica por ende en Arduino para poder tomar ese valor necesitas conectar el pin de salida de tu sensor de temperatura a una entrada Analogica de la placa Arduino.

En este caso tu defines el pin del sensor en el pin numero uno que es un pin digital, por lo que tu necesitas un pin analogico por ejemplo **A0**, **A2**, **A3** por que con los pines digitales solo se reciben valores logicos que son entre **0V** y **5V** y los pines Analogicos reciben valores mas pequeños de voltaje que van en un rango de mV (milivoltios), en fin te dejo un diagrama de los pines del Arduino para que conozcas bien los pines de la placa.

En fin espero que con esto te orientes un poco saludos...
[image: Puertos de la placa Arduino]

En la parte donde tienes el siguiente fragmento de codigo:

```
if(temp2>='20'HIGH)
```

tienes un problema ya que intentas poner un valor lógico y un valor numérico a la vez, ya que estas realizando una conversión previamente de los valores obtenidos de tu sensor por lo que solo seria necesario poner valores numéricos en este caso:

```
if(temp2>=20)
```

Comment: muchas gracias ha sido de mucha ayuda